# How to choose between same name elements with different attribute

Tags: xslt

Given this input:

```
<place>
    <name lang="en">english_nameA</name>
    <name lang="fr">french_nameA</name>
</place>
<place>
    <name lang="en">english_nameB</name>
</place>
```

I would like to select (let's say put to an HTML table) the name of place in french if it is availiable or in english if it is not availiable in french.

How could this be done in xslt?

Comment: There are many ways. The most straightforward would be to use `xsl:choose`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify an XPath that selects the name where `@lang='fr'`, but if there are no name elements with `@lang='fr'` then select the one with `@lang='en'`

```
<xsl:template match="place">
    <xsl:value-of select="name[@lang='fr' or 
                               @lang='en' and not(../name/@lang='fr')]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

With **XSLT 2.0** or **3.0**, you could also select them in a sequence with the preferred values first, then select the first value in the sequence:

```
<xsl:template match="place">
    <xsl:value-of select="(name[@lang='fr'], name[@lang='en'])[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If there is no `fr` value, then the first in the sequence would be `en`. You could then apply multiple "tiers" of preferred languages, and even specify a default value when none are present.